# How to get hadoop reducer results in a collection(array, set, etc.)?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, reduce

I'm writing a program that would process the results of the reducer before making some output, like

```
Mapper
Reducer
Processing
Output
```

It's impossible to integrate the `Processing` part in the `Reducer` part, but from the first day of learning Hadoop (word count example), we are taught to put the results of the reducer into a file.

Is it possible to get the result as an array, ArrayList, Set, etc. without having to output them in a file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can write your code in OutputFormatter